How to maintain `git status` while removing all historical file data?
I want to embed a Git repository in my Docker image. I have two wishes for it:

Information about the checked-out version should be available (e.g. git status, git describe --tags) such that users could verify which exact software got embedded in their Docker image. The exact Git commit hash should be available.
To minimize the size of the Docker image, all information of file changes in the past should be removed (those aren't relevant anyway, git checkout does not
need to work anymore inside the Docker image).

How could I accomplish this? Which files can I delete without breaking Git?
My work folder is now like this:
project/
├─ Dockerfile
├─ my_repo/
│  ├─ .git/
│  ├─ ...

Another caveat: git fetch and the likes cannot be used because the Docker image has no access to the repository remote.

EDIT:
The suggestion of a new shallow Git clone from the existing clone below is useful.
But I was misunderstanding something about Docker and this won't actually decrease my image size at all, see: https://forums.docker.com/t/why-run-command-which-deletes-files-inflates-image-size/33670
Since a COPY ... command already creates its own layer, removing some files in a next RUN ... command doesn't reduce the overall image size.

Don't.  The world needs to stop using git as a distribution tool.  It is not designed for that, and it is not good at that.  Build a package (eg rpm or dep or whatever is appropriate) or build some artifact of some kind.  Even if you are just generating a source tarball via a 1990's style autoconfiscated make dist, do that instead.   Or just use git-archive and create a tarball with the oid in the name.

Thanks for the heads-up. In my case I need to wrap up squeaky legacy code in Docker so it can be run again on modern machines. The images are tagged with the code version already, I figured it would be useful if the code Git information would be visible too.

If you have a full local clone of the repo, you can create a shallow version (with only the last commit) from it by cloning it into another directory locally:
git clone --depth 1 --no-local /path/to/full/repo

The --no-local flag is needed to disable gits local optimizations, which don't work with the --depth flag.
You can the remove the fully cloned repo.

The OP wants git describe --tags, shallow clone with git clone --depth 1 prevents this.

Ah right, 'shallow' is the word for what I want in Git. Using git clone --depth 1 file://<absolute path to repo> did the trick for me, and git describe --tags --always still works afterwards! (However, I realized another big problem, see my edit in the question.)
